# Azure Application Insight : Activity logs Export to EventHub , EventHubTrigger Function is not executed after export

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Application Insight to see activity logs. When I select activity logs and do export to Event Hub option in Azure portal, I want Trigger to be executed for that selected Event Hub.

I have configured EventHubTrigger Azure Function which do processing on activity logs received on selected Event Hub.

I can see in Event Hub portal dashboard that Request are received on Event Hub still its Trigger is not executed.

When I send events manually via Java Event Producer application then my Event Hub Trigger Azure Function being executed.

Could anyone please help me why EventHub Trigger is not executed when I do export in EventHub (using Azure Application Insight) though EventHub received that events/requests.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I am still working on this. One possibility is that there might be missing config. I will raise ticket with Azure otherwise.